# Couchbase - Data Eviction

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

I am using "value eviction" for deleting data from RAM. Is there a way to find the oldest document with both data + metadata in the bucket (in RAM)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do what you're asking, because Couchbase doesn't expose these internal parameters. However, perhaps there is another way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do. Could you please describe what you want to accomplish?

Edited in response to the comment below:

As a general rule, you should use the default (value eviction) unless you have a compelling reason to switch to full eviction. Even though, ostensibly, you "save" more RAM by using full eviction, you're actually trading off performance on some operations that will now have to hit the disk instead of returning a response from memory. Specifically, cache misses or existence checks are more expensive (IO-wise), as well as some types of update operations.

Some cases where you would consider using full eviction are when your dataset is much larger than your working set (i.e the 'hot' data that's accessed frequently and should be in cache), or when you have to store a very large number of small values, such as when keeping a mapping of GUID-to-GUID, which means that the value is actually smaller than the metadata+key.

Comment: Thanks David. I am trying to decide between full eviction and value eviction. I currently have value eviction set which would retain the metadata even if data is evicted. When I change it to full eviction , both data and meta-data will be lost. I am trying to see what is the oldest data that has both data and meta-data , which would enable to determine if I need to choose full eviction. For instance , if the data is cached in RAM for 2 weeks generally before it is evicted , I am good. If not , I have to look for other options.

Comment: Updated my original answer.